# converting a string to image in c# for windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

i want to convert a string entered by user to an image..how can it be done?
i tried the following code but i get an argument exception in the line :
WriteableBitmap wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);

```
    static public string EncodeTo64(string toEncode)
    {
        byte[] toEncodeAsBytes
              = StringToAscii(toEncode);
        string returnValue
              = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public static byte[] StringToAscii(string s)
    {
        byte[] retval = new byte[s.Length];
        for (int ix = 0; ix < s.Length; ++ix)
        {
            char ch = s[ix];


            if (ch <= 0x7f)  retval[ix] = (byte)ch; 
            else  retval[ix] = (byte)'?'; 
        }

        return retval;
    }
    void convert()
    {
        String s = textBox1.Text;
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(EncodeTo64(s));

        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data[i]);
        }
        Stream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        memStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);


        try
        {
        WriteableBitmap wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);

        image1.Source = wbimg;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        }

    }
```

I got what i wanted in the following links.. [How can I render text on a WriteableBitmap on a background thread, in Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666772/how-can-i-render-text-on-a-writeablebitmap-on-a-background-thread-in-windows-ph) and http://blogs.u2u.be/michael/post/2011/04/20/Adding-a-text-to-an-image-in-WP7.aspx Thanks to all those who replied for the initial help! :)

Comment: I'm confused, what's the goal? The user will enter a long sequence non-human-readable bytes to convert to JPG?   Or are you trying to do something like have them enter "Hello" and you create an image with that text?  Two completely different things.

Comment: Something like have them enter "Hello" and you create an image with that text. Thats the goal.

Comment: ah ok, then you're quite a ways off :)  You basically need to use internal drawing APIs to accomplish what you want - this reference may be a start: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: hey, can you please give me an example for doing it using writeablebitmapex.

Answer (score 2):

It is the simple way you can convert **TextBlock Text into Image**

```
    private void convert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Canvas c1 = new Canvas();
        TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
        t.Text = text1.Text;
        t.FontFamily = text1.FontFamily;
        t.Foreground = text1.Foreground;
        t.FontSize = text1.FontSize;
        c1.Children.Add(t);
        WriteableBitmap wbmp = new WriteableBitmap(c1, null);
        im = new Image();
        im.Source = wbmp;
        im.Height = 200;
        im.Width = 200;     
        Canvas.SetTop(im, 10);
        Canvas.SetLeft(im, 10);

        Main_Canvas.Children.Add(im);
    }
```

Here I convert the Textblock Text into Bitmap and then assign it to the image source.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to writte a string to a bitmap:

```
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(200, 100);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        g.DrawString("My sample string", new Font("Tahoma",10), Brushes.Red, new Point(0, 0));
        b.Save("mypic.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        g.Dispose();
        b.Dispose();
```

Shubhi1910 let me know if you need any details to be explained.

Comment: Hey, I guess system.drawing does not exist for windows phone.