# Outer Glow Effect for TextBlock in WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xaml, windows-runtime

WinRT doesn't have `OuterGlowBitmapEffect`. So, is there any way to display the outer glow effect for a `TextBlock` in WinRT?

Comment: What type of content do you want to apply a glow to? Is it text, vectors or bitmaps and does is it static or not?

Comment: If you don't want to use HTML and CSS I would go with 2nd option I posted unless you need to support many fonts and sizes or paragraphs of text. It would need a few tweaks for WinRT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a good way to apply effects to XAML content, WinRT also currently lacks a way to render XAML elements to a bitmap so you are mainly left with methods where you don't use XAML.

Make sure the glow is necessary and you have reviewed the [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779072.aspx) for Windows 8 apps.
If your sure you need it here are a few suggestions:

- For simple cases you may be able to use gradients or duplicated geometry to get a glow affect.
- Bundle graphics with the glow already applied with your app, this obviously wouldn't work for completely dynamic shapes but you could do it for text similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719750/best-way-to-get-a-glow-effect-windows-phone-7/5438724#5438724).
- Use Direct2D instead of XAML and use [Direct2D effects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh706316) ([SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) offers bindings for Direct2D)
- If you need to apply a glow to a bitmap you could use a WriteableBitmap and apply the glow yourself. ([WriteableBitmapEX](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/releases/view/39577) could be useful)
- Use HTML and CSS instead of XAML, possibly hosted in a WebView or for the whole app.

Comment: I have to display text on a image which has both light and dark background so I really need to use the outer glow effect.

Comment: Putting a black textblock under a white one and shifting it diagonally would make the text visible but if you do need a glow the 2nd and 3rd options would work. I can look at updating the code for WinRT if needed. This is much simpler in HTML as text-shadow is supported.